# SocketException: OS Error: Connection refused, errno = 111 in flutter remote server

Tags: android, flutter, sockets

Trying to create token using the following command. The reques fails with  'SocketException: OS Error: Connection refused, errno = 111'. I am trying it on real device with build release and connecting to remote server(Not local host). The issue happends only when connected to wifi network.

I suppose its a network issue rather than flutter issue. But anyone could explain why this happens and any possible solution for this issue?

NB: Internet permission request added to android manifest file.

```
  await get(url,headers: headers).then(onTokenCreation).catchError(onError);
```

Comment: `Connection refused, errno = 111 in flutter remote server` How should i read this? There was a connection and then the server refused to communicate and closed the connection? Who gives the error message? That server or your client app?

Comment: I think you should tell/show how your url looks like.

Comment: SocketException: OS Error: Connection refused, errno = 111, address = rand.XXXXX.com, port=38640. This is the exact error coming in. I am catching the error using catchError function

Comment: You did not answer my question.

Comment: The app gives the error.

Comment: Ok. The app can not connect. And now about the url...

Comment: Its a live system so I cant give the url due to security reason. But this works fine with postman and other applications using .Net and php. Even this app works fine with mobile data. Issue is only when connected using wifi

Comment: http://test.server.com/oauth/token?username=$userName&password=$password&terminal=$terminal&grant_type=password. Its a http request. Not https

Comment: ` http://test.server.com/oauth/token?username=$userName&password=$password&terminal=$terminal&grant_type=password `

Comment: `http://test.server.com/oauth/token?username=$userName&password=$password&terminal=$terminal&grant_type=password`

Comment: Ok. Which Android version on used device? For instance on Android 11 (and maybe earlier) http traffic is not possible. Unless you did add `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` to application tag in manifest file?

Comment: I havent added that code. But it works on my phone. But when client testing, its not working

Comment: What is client testing?

Comment: Same app but with a different wifi. On his wifi we get this error

Comment: You mean wifi of a different router?

Comment: Yes. Different wifi. I think its a problem with their network. But need to give a proper explanation

Comment: Try with ip address instead of domain name.